# The below snippet is able to generate the error level logs but is not injecting into the file

Tags: logging, rolling-computation, rollingfileappender, errorlevel, logback-groovy

I am expecting that only error level logs will also be injecting the file. So i have applied this filter tag to filter out the error level logs.
but the error logs are not injecting into the file

```
<configuration>
    <property name="APP_NAME" value="seeder" />
    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="/var/log/fraudnet/seeder" />
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
    <appender name="DebugFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/fraudnet/seeder/seeder-%d{yyyy-MM}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5level %logger{0}: %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ErrorFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}-error.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}-error.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d] [%t] %X{ipaddress} %X{username} %-5p %c{2} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.the41" level="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="DebugFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="ErrorFile" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```